# "in bold letters" vs. "in bold"

Tags: phrase-choice

I wonder which form(s) are correct amongst the following:

> The pronouns present in the text are marked **in bold.**
>
> The pronouns present in the text are marked **in bold letters**.

Comment: Just in bold. "The pronouns present in the text are marked in **bold**."

Comment: There's nothing wrong with either of them... another option is "in bold lettering" or "in bold text"... it's all up to you.

Comment: Either is acceptable and their meanings are identical.

Comment: @MarkHubbard, Both are correct.Here is an Ngram for "in bold letters". https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+bold+letters&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20bold%20letters%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just use "in bold."

Including "letters" is not incorrect, but omitting it is more common.

However, if you were describing the design of the letters, you might refer to a particular design as "a bold typeface," or "a bold font." The difference between *typeface* and *font* is another question for another day – they're generally interchangeable in normal conversation and writing, but in a technical discussion they refer to different things.

Another related term is [*to embolden*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/embolden), which is the verb for causing text to appear in bold. It's falling out of favour now, and you're unlikely to see it outside of formal texts. In common conversation, you're more likely to hear *to bold* or *to make bold* in its place.